# Elements of array ref used in multiple hashes not shown

Tags: perl, hashref, arrayref

In the following code when the contents of array are printed key3 of hashref2 does not have the desired values (What I wan to achieve is hashref1 to have an array in key3 with value1 and hashref2 to have an array in key3 with value2).

In the code flow I need to first populated hashrefs and then push data to the subarray.

Can you please advice if the use of reference to subarray is the right way to go here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array;
my @subarray;


# Puash to array
my $hashref1 = {
  key1 => 'value1_1',
  key2 => 'value1_2',
  key3 => \@subarray
};
push (@array, $hashref1);

# push some data in subarray
push (@subarray, 'value1');

# clear subarray
splice(@subarray);

# Puash to array
my $hashref2 = {
  key1 => 'value2_1',
  key2 => 'value2_2',
  key3 => \@subarray
};
push (@array, $hashref2);

# push some data in subarray
push (@subarray, 'value2');

print  "hashref1:\n".Dumper($hashref1);
print  "hashref2:\n".Dumper($hashref2);

print  "array:\n".Dumper(@array);
```

out:

```
hashref1:
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'value1_2',
          'key1' => 'value1_1',
          'key3' => [
                      'value2'
                    ]
        };
hashref2:
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'value2_2',
          'key1' => 'value2_1',
          'key3' => [
                      'value2'
                    ]
        };
array:
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'value1_2',
          'key1' => 'value1_1',
          'key3' => [
                      'value2'
                    ]
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'key2' => 'value2_2',
          'key1' => 'value2_1',
          'key3' => $VAR1->{'key3'}
        };
```

Comment: By the way, `Dumper(@array)` should be `Dumper(\@array)`. Passing arrays or hashes to `Dumper` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just don't fully understand how references work. You're basically pushing a reference to the same array, so no wonder you have exact same contents of this array.

What you need to do is to create a new array reference. Here's the proper code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array;
my $subarray = [];


# Puash to array
my $hashref1 = {
  key1 => 'value1_1',
  key2 => 'value1_2',
  key3 => $subarray
};
push (@array, $hashref1);

# push some data in subarray
push ( @$subarray, 'value1' );

# create a new subarray
$subarray = [];

# Puash to array
my $hashref2 = {
  key1 => 'value2_1',
  key2 => 'value2_2',
  key3 => $subarray
};
push (@array, $hashref2);

# push some data in subarray
push ( @$subarray, 'value2' );

print  "hashref1:\n".Dumper($hashref1);
print  "hashref2:\n".Dumper($hashref2);

print  "array:\n".Dumper(@array);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are storing references to the *same* array in all of your hash references. This means if you modify `@subarray`, all of the hashes that have references to it appear to change in unison.

Instead make separate shallow copies as in

```
@subarray = ('value2');
my $hashref2 = {
  key1 => 'value2_1',
  key2 => 'value2_2',
  key3 =>  [ @subarray ],
};
push (@array, $hashref2);
```